# Can we connect to both Bigtable and Hive from one spark session?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, google-cloud-bigtable

I am following the example from below link 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/scala/bigtable-shc
to connect to bigtable from a scala application that's using Spark. We have some data in GCS which we connect to using hive. We need to be able to connect to hive and get the data and write it into BigTable.

I added configuration for BigTable in hbase-site.xml file. I added hive properties to the config while starting the spark session. Can a spark session be able to connect to two different datasources at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to connect to both hive and bigtable. I had to use the below configuration.

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName(appName)
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","gs://<bucket-name>/user/hive/warehouse/")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate
```